# adding text to caroufredsel slideshow

Tags: java, jquery, html, slideshow, caroufredsel

Hey this should be a simple fix but theres something going wrong that i cant seem to figure out. ive got the text to show up but text from each slide shows up at the same time even though each div in within the li tags... 
any help would be great, thanks in advance.

```
<div class="image_carousel">  
                                <ul id="foo2">
                                    <li><img src="img/slideshow/slide1.jpg" style="border:none;" alt="Image 1" /><div class="headertext">TEST 1</div></li>
                                    <li><img src="img/slideshow/slide2.jpg" style="border:none;"  alt="Image 2" /><div class="headertext">TEST 2</div></li>
                                    <li><img src="img/slideshow/slide3.jpg" style="border:none;"  alt="Image 3" /><div class="headertext">TEST 3</div></li>
                                    </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="pagination" id="foo2_pag"></div>
                <div id="overlay"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to see your CSS it is hard to distinguish what the problem may be.

The text should move along with the image as it is within the same list item leading me to believe your 'headertext' div will has some absolute positioning (or something similar) causing it not to slide through with the image.

If you have a link to your CSS or Website I may be able to give you a better idea.